# How to save form by using Input type = "datetime-local" In Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

In my form i have an input field of **ENDDATE AND TIME** but when i select end date and time and i give submit the form was not valid.  Here i have mentioned my html, views.py models.py and form.py. i don't why its happening so please help me to do this.

**HTML**

```
<label>End Date & Time</label>
  <div >
     <input class="form-control" id="party"  type = "datetime-local" name="end_date">
   </div>
```

**Views.py**

```
def event(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EventForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, "Insertion Success!")
            return redirect('/event')
        else:

            messages.success(request,"You missed to fill some fields!")
            return HttpResponse(form)
```

**form.py**

```
class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = Events
       fields = ['end_date']
       widgets = {
        'end_date': DateTimeInput(attrs={'type': 'datetime-local'}),
}
```

**models.py**

```
class Events(models.Model):
    end_date =models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False,blank=True)
```

Comment: If you output `{{ form.errors }}` in your template, then Django will *tell* you why it is not valid.

Comment: I guess the `DateTimeInput` is returning a string and `DateTimeField` is expecting a `list`

Comment: @DanielRoseman @Vineeth Sai I have removed widgets in form.py if i try to save form was not valid `return HttpResponse(form)`  it returns like in this format `2018-10-05T01:01` but expected output like `2018-10-05T11:11:00Z` so please help me to do this  thank you.

Comment: Truly an infuriating problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div >
     <input class="form-control" id="party"  type = "datetime-local" name="end_date">
   </div>
```

This code must include **form** template for  rendering form

Change code to this:

```
<form>
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p  }}
</form>
```

In event view change use something like this code:

```
from .forms import EventForm 
def event(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EventForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, "Insertion Success!")
            return redirect('/event')
        else:

            messages.success(request,"You missed to fill some fields!")
            return HttpResponse(form)

    else:
        form=EventForm()
        return render(request,'your template name ',context={'form':form})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the format in the field, in addition to the widget.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53194594/3057341